# glass light pass through

Tags: light

[image]

I have this situation, i created a scene, where light bulbs should be the light source. I managed to get the light through bulbs, but the emission coefficient is 5000, with that, the scene should be bright as sun. As you can see, it is not. And when the bulb is in the glass, light is nowhere.

Caustics are on, all bounces at 128 or more. So I guess it is somewhere in material setting, I tried to play with light paths but this was the best I achieved.

So if you know/have something that would help me, i would be really glad.

[image]

I did something similar in Rhinoceros, so i would like to get similar result also in blender
[image: I did something similar in Rhinoceros, so i would like to get similar result also in blender]

Comment: Try enabling Multiple Importance in lamp settings tab

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10434/599

Comment: see also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/light-bulb-filaments-brightness-and-internal-reflections-in-cycles