# Light bulb glass material very dark

Tags: materials, light, shaders

I made a light bulb and I use the Glass BSDF material. I also use solidify modifier to get some thickness of the glass, but the problem that I can't find a solution for is why the glass is soo dark. I want it almost pure transparent. I have read other questions here in the forum about this and I have set the white color to 100% and I also increased the value for the transmission bounces in the laight paths panel and turned off the shadow. The room is full of light.

What can I do to change and improve the render of the light bulbs?

[image]

Comment: Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles?rq=1 but it's hard to tell as you don't provide node setup

Comment: @MrZak The node setup is very simple, it's only the Glass BSDF node and the Material Output node for the light bulb. But I have solved the problem. I had previously reduced the number of max bounces to two for faster render. After I increased the value, the black glass was gone and now looks ok!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/spherical-emitter-does-not-illuminate-very-well and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/light-bulb-filaments-brightness-and-internal-reflections-in-cycles