# Trying to recreate an effect that involves emission and cant get it right at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, glass

this is a picture of the effect I am doing

[image]

The original work: https://instagram.com/p/BjFdQfEgthj/

I just can't seem to get the same glow like effect. I'm not sure if I am missing something with the emission material itself or is it the surrounding elements that are making it realistic.

when I made it I just added an emission shader, I'm assuming there should be other stuff with it too but mine just ended up looking extremely dull. ignoring the imperfections on the glass, the glow in mine is just meh and not even glowing at all. am I missing something big with emissions? increasing the emission value just makes it white so that didnt help either

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender) also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender or just: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=glow

Comment: You need to increase the value for the emission, also the glass shader by itself will not work. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/spherical-emitter-does-not-illuminate-very-well and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/light-bulb-filaments-brightness-and-internal-reflections-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56647/glass-render-problem/57968#57968 also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow/43250#43250

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Volume Scattering.
In the world tab (icon of globe), under "Volume", select "Volume Scatter" from the dropdown and set up the Density and Antisotropy to be similar to mine (feel free to tweak but this should work well):
[image]
This brought my emission object from this
[image]
To this:
[image]

Again, feel free to play with any of the values shown to get it to look as you imagine!

Comment: adding the volume scatter removes everything else from my scene, cant see the lamps or the background plane i added