# Faint duplication of elements seen through glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

Made these simple lightbulbs in a quest to understand blender lighting when I encountered a problem with the render not only faintly duplicating my light source but also the thin wires in the other lightbulb too...
Also I'm using the filmic log encoding color management and cycles render.

[image: Wires looking awful]
Object mode shows one wire inside

[image]
But render preview already shows 3 wires on 5 samples

[image: Screenshot]

I think something is up with my glass

Comment: Isn't that a reflection off of the far inside surface of the bulb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [light bulb filament brightness and internal reflections in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/light-bulb-filaments-brightness-and-internal-reflections-in-cycles)

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56647/glass-render-problem/57968?r=SearchResults#57968

Comment: As a side note, those black artifacts in the rendered image, are caused by the denoiser. Don't use denoise, use clamp indirect instead. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96101/problems-with-denoising-in-rendering/97491?r=SearchResults#97491